# JAVA: How to write a loop that computes sum of series

Tags: java, sum, series

How do I write a loop that compute a sum of following series if
the series is `1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6 ....`?

Compute this until the denominator is 1000. i.e. 1/1000
and print the resulting value?

Comment: what have tried so far?

Comment: You can use the keyboard.

Comment: @Guy keyboard? Pfft, [real programmers use butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: So any progress on your assignment? Have you tried something so far? Edit your post with what you have tried and people will be much nicer you will see!

Answer (score 1):

```
double sum = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++) {
    sum += (double) 1 / (double) i * (double) Math.pow(-1, i + 1);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

In this, `i` is your denominator becoming incremented for every item of the sequence that the series is based on. The (i + 1)th power of -1 makes the sign switch from - to + in the desired way.

However, this is very basic stuff. Maybe you want to consider to read a book about programming or alternately about maths or do some online tutorials, if you need to ask such questions.

Comment: You can also try the following if/else loop using modulo if you are not comfortable with function/class  `double sum=1;
    for(int i=2;i<=1000;i++)
    {
     if(i%2!=0)
      {sum+=1.0/i;}
     else
      {sum-=1.0/i;}     
    }
    System.out.println("result= "+sum);
     } `

Comment: @Allan This could also be a good idea considering the runtime behavior for greater denominator bounds than 1000. When `i` becomes really big and the compiler/interpreter does not abbreviate the function some way when translating to assembler code, it could eventually take some time to calculate an (i + 1)th power.